# MS SQL version of TO_DATE query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a query to see a table details

```
select APPLICATION_NAME,
SOURCE,
IDENTITY_NAME,
IDENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME,
NATIVE_IDENTITY,
ACCOUNT_DISPLAY_NAME,
OPERATION,
STATUS,
CREATED, 
(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + created / 86400000) AS CREATED_DATE
```

It looks like this query is for MySQL. However, our database is hosted in Microsoft SQL. Hence I am getting below error when running the query

**'TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

Could you please suggest an equivalent command of TO_DATE and how to modify it in the above query

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need to do any such thing in MySQL either - both databases have date types. You'll have to fix the MySQL database too, as soon as people realize this makes them vurnerable to the Y2K38 issue.

Comment: Just change `created` to a proper date type, eg [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which allows you to specify fractional second precision and actually takes *less* space than a bigint for millisecond accuracy. Or use [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you don't want the time component

Comment: SQL Server has `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions for converting text dates to date types, and vice-versa. But, as has been suggested, better to work with date types.

Comment: `CAST(DATE, '1970-01-01', 23)`

Comment: Again, **what are you trying to do??** What does `created` contain? You don't need to do tricks like that, you could just use `DATEADD` to add the seconds or milliseconds to a base date.

Comment: `dateadd('ms',created,cast('1970-01-01' as date))` is enough if `created` contains milliseconds. `dateadd('s',created,cast('1970-01-01' as date))` for seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DATEADD for adding to the datetime and CONVERT to set your string to a Datetime type:

```
--Using the DateAdd to add parts to the date and Tehe CONVERT to set your string to a datetime
    SELECT DATEADD(MS, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01')) -- Add 10 Milliseconds
    SELECT DATEADD(S, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01')) -- Add 10 Seconds
    SELECT DATEADD(N, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01')) -- Add 10 Minutes
    SELECT DATEADD(HH, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01')) -- Add 10 Hours
    SELECT DATEADD(D, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01')) -- Add 10 Days
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `created` is an epoch timestamp, stored in milliseconds (86400000 is how many milliseconds there are in one day). If so, I think that you want:

```
DATEADD(ms, created, '1970-01-01') AS CREATED_DATE
```

Side note: `TO_DATE()` is Oracle syntax, not MySQL. The most important thing to change in your original query is date arithmetics: Oracle allows adding days to a `date`, while most other databases don't. On the other hand, SQL Server does not support standard interval arithmetics (we need to use `DATEADD()`).

Comment: The OP wants to convert this to T-SQL. Looks like `created` stores a Unix epoch instead of a proper datetime-related value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: fixed now.

Comment: It should probably be `ms`, since the OP divides by 86400000, not 86400. We can't be sure though, since there's no sample data yet

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted (along wih all other answers here)? Downvoter, please elaborate.